# How can I `catch` an exception within a Yesod Handler?

Tags: haskell, yesod, monad-transformers

When I tried:

```
foos <- (return $ map (encode .> cs .> jsonToFoo body) `catch` r400
```

I got the following type error:

```
/path/to/File.hs:47:78: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘(->) e0’ with ‘IO’
        arising from a functional dependency between:
          constraint ‘MonadBase IO ((->) e0)’ arising from a use of ‘r400’
          instance ‘MonadBase ((->) r) ((->) r)’ at <no location info>
    • In the second argument of ‘catch’, namely ‘r400’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        foos <- (return $ map (encode .> cs .> jsonToFoo) body)
                `catch` r400
      In the expression:
        do { (body :: [Value]) <- requireJsonBody;
             foos <- (return $ map (encode .> cs .> jsonToFoo) body)
                     `catch` r400;
             .... }
```

If there is a way, it involves `liftIO`, doesn't it?

Comment: Try using [the version of `catch` from the lifted-base package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lifted-base-0.2.3.10/docs/Control-Exception-Lifted.html#v:catch).

Comment: @AlexisKing Thanks, giving that a try.

Comment: @AlexisKing I get the exact same type error: `Couldn't match type ‘(->) e0’ with ‘IO’`

Comment: @AlexisKing Nevermind that. I was just missing the argument: `(\(e ::  SomeException) -> r400)`.

Comment: I guess it just wasn't clear at first glance from the type error for either of us :)

Comment: Oh, and while it works with `lifted-base` too, It works without it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was just missing the argument for `catch`:

```
foos <- (return $ map (encode .> cs .> jsonToFoo body)
  `catch` (\(e :: SomeException) -> r400)
```

Too bad it wasn't more apparent for me from the type error.